# Table trigger to indicate two records were merged

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have some simple triggers on a table which work for to audit changes to a record by logging to a table any time an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` occurs. When a record is inserted into `Users`, a copy is made in `Users_History` with a `Status` field populated with the value `'INSERT'`. Same is done for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Users_History_Insert AFTER INSERT ON Audit
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO Users_History select *, 'INSERT' from Users where ID = NEW.ID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Users_History_Delete BEFORE DELETE ON Audit
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO Users_History select *, 'DELETE' from Users where ID = OLD.ID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Users_History_Update AFTER UPDATE ON Audit
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO Users_History select *, 'UPDATE' from Users where ID = NEW.ID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

We have a function where two `Users` records can be merged with each other. Effectively, all values of one record are overwritten with the values of another record, and the unchanged record is deleted.

If you had a table such as this:

```
| ID | Name  |  email         |
| 1  | Billy | bill@mail.com  |
| 2  | Bill  | bill2@mail.com |
```

And I wanted to merge record 2 into 1, I'd end up with this result.

```
| ID | Name |  email          |
| 1  | Bill | bill2@mail.com  |
```

I'd like to create a trigger that would have this in `Users_History` where 2 is the record merged from.

```
| Users_ID | Name | Email          | Status   |
| 1        | Bill | bill2@mail.com | MERGED:2 |
```

As it stands now, we would end up with two records, an `UPDATE` and a `DELETE`

```
UPDATE `Users_To`
SET `Name` = `Users_From`.`Name`, `email` = `Users_From`.`email`
FROM `Users` AS `Users_To`
CROSS JOIN `Users` AS `Users_From`
WHERE `Users_To`.`ID` = 1 AND `Users_From`.`ID` = 2;

DELETE FROM `Users` WHERE `ID` = 2;
```

I can't think of a way to do this in SQL, is it possible? As I understand, the triggers have no knowledge of the `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause affecting a record.

Comment: That's two different queries (one `update`, then one `delete`), so there is no way your triggers can pick on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE query has a flaw and is correctly

```
UPDATE `Users` AS `Users_To` CROSS JOIN `Users` AS `Users_From`
SET `Users_To`.`Name` = `Users_From`.`Name`, `Users_To`.`email` = `Users_From`.`email`
WHERE `Users_To`.`ID` = 1 AND `Users_From`.`ID` = 2;
DELETE FROM `Users` WHERE `ID` = 2;
```

What the trigger does is simple first it check if the update is a modify of an existing row by checking if there are mor than one rows with the same email.

If that the case grab the other id in your case 2 and add it ti the text.

This works as long you have only 2 rows involved in your update query.

And i don't know your  your table, but if you have a UNIQUE constraint you will have a problem with the update.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Users_History_Update;
CREATE TRIGGER Users_History_Update AFTER UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    SELECT Count(*) INTO @number FROM Users WHERE `email` = NEW.`email`;
    IF @number > 1 THEN
        SELECT `ID` INTO @id FROM Users WHERE `email` = NEW.`email` AND `ID` <> NEW.`ID`;
        INSERT INTO Users_History VALUES (OLD.`ID`,OLD.`Name` ,OLD.`email`, CONCAT('MERGED:',@id));
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Users_History VALUES (OLD.`ID`,OLD.`Name` ,OLD.`email`, 'UPDATE');
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```